# Model categories--Quillen adjunction Left and Right Quillen functor

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, model-categories

In the book Model categories on the page 14,
do they assume that
    $U$
    in
    3.
    (so that $(F,U,\phi)$ is a Quillen adjunction)
    is a RIGHT QUILLEN FUNCTOR or just
    Right adjoint WITHOUT the preservation of fibrations and trivial fibrations?
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: $F$ is a left Quillen functor iff $U$ is a right Quillen functor,  see Lemma 1.3.4

Comment: Based on this definition, the right adjoint is not a priori assumed to preserve fibrations and trivial fibrations. However, as @Nick commented, it follows from the fact that the left adjoint preserves cofibrations and trivial cofibrations.

Comment: @Berci I have included the lemma 1.3.4 into my OQ. However I do not follow the proof there, namely what is $f$, $p$ and how do I use adjointeness to show that $Ff$ has the l.l.p.. w.r.t. $p$ iff $f$ has the l.l.p. w.r.t. $Up$. Can you give me a hint ?

Comment: $f$ is an arbitrary arrow in $\mathcal C$ and $p$ is an arbitrary arrow in $\mathcal D$. Can you prove the given statement?

Comment: @Berci Not yet, I cannot prove it. Adjuction has always been a mystery for me.

Comment: For another perspective of adjunctions, one can regard the two functors as one *profunctor*, check out https://zellerede.ml/profunctors

Answer (score 2):

As is commented, Lemma 1.3.4. answers your question: though this definition of Quillen adjunction is not a priori assuming $U$ to preserve fibrations and trivial fibrations, it still holds as a consequence.

We use that the cofibrations can be described as those maps which have the left lifting property for trivial fibrations, and a similar description for trivial cofibrations.

Now, let $f:A\to B\, \in\mathcal C$ and $p:D\to E\, \in \mathcal D$ be arbitrary arrows. 
Then the following commutative squares correspond to each other, using the adjunction:
$$\matrix{A&\longrightarrow & UD\\ f\downarrow\phantom{f} && \phantom{Up}\downarrow Up \\ B & \longrightarrow & UE} 
\quad\quad \leftrightarrow\quad\quad
\matrix{FA&\longrightarrow & D\\ Ff\downarrow\phantom{Ff} && \phantom{p}\downarrow p\\ FB & \longrightarrow & E} $$
Also, any diagonal fill-in arrow $B\to UD$ in the left square corresponds to a diagonal fill-in $FB\to D$ in the right square.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: I cannot see now what remaines to be shown ...

Comment: Well, it's indeed straightforward: So if $p$ is a fibration and $f$ is a trivial cofibration, then so is $Ff$, therefore there is a diagonal fill-in in the right square, hence also in the left square, thus $f$ has l.l.p. w.r.t $Up$, and since $f$ was arbitrary, $Up$ is a fibration.

Comment: I now understand everything but for this:" Also, any diagonal fill-in arrow $B\to UD$ in the left square corresponds to a diagonal fill-in $FB\to D$ in the right square." Could you clarify this for me (i.e. how the adjunction applies here)? Also, I do not follow how did you derive that $Up$ is a fibration from the fact that $f$ was an arbitrary trivial cofibration and from the fact that $Up$ has the r.l.p. w.r.t. $f$, please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3588230/model-categories-trivial-fibrations-and-cofibrations-l-l-p)

Comment: I think that **if** $Up$ is a fibration **then** it has r.l.p. w.r.t. $f$ and **not** that if it has r.l.p. w.r.t. $f$ **then it is a fibration** ! Is there for the non-obvious direction a place from which it follows in the Hovey's book ?

Comment: @user122424 This is lemma 1.1.10 in Hovey's book.

Comment: @Berci Please, how can I see that if the 2 triangles in the l.h.s. square in your answer commute **then** the 2 triangles given by the adjunction **also commute** ?

Comment: For an intuition to see this, consider the following category: take the disjoint union of $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ and define additional arrows ('*heteromorphisms*') $C\to D$ as arrows $FC\to D$ of $\mathcal D$ (or equivalently, as arrows $C\to GD$ of $\mathcal C$), define compositions in the straightforward way. In this category $\mathcal C$ is a coreflective full subcategory, and $\mathcal D$ is a reflective full subcategory. Then the two squares above both correspond to the same square (with opposite borders $f$ and $p$) in this bigger category. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Berci The intuition is quite good but it is not entire and convincing proof. The situation,however, *deserves* a proof , say one along these lines: $F(g\circ f)=F(g)\circ F(f)$ *since $F$ is a functor*. Could you please still help?