# Model categories, trivial fibrations and cofibrations l.l.p.

Tags: category-theory, model-categories, cofibrations

> **Defintion** $\bf 1.1.2~$ Suppose $i:A\to B$ and $p:X\to Y$ are maps in a category $\mathcal C$. Then $i$ has the *left lifting property with respect to* $p$ and $p$ has the *right lifting property with respect to* $i$ if, for every commutative diagramm
> $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> A @>{f}>> X\\
> @V{i}VV @VV{p}V \\
> B @>{g}>> Y
> \end{CD}$$
> there is a lift $h:B\to Y$ such that $hi=f$ and $ph=g$.

---

> **Definition** $\bf 1.1.3~$ A *model structure* on a category $\mathcal C$ is three subcategories of $\mathcal C$ called weak equivalences, cofibrations, and fibrations, and two functorial factorizations $(\alpha,\beta)$ and $(\gamma,\delta)$ satisfying the following properties:
>
> 1. ($2$-out-of-$3$) If $f$ and $g$ are morphisms of $\mathcal C$ such that $gf$ is defined and two of $f,g$ and $gf$ are weak equivalences, then so is the third.
> 2. (Retracts) If $f$ and  $g$ are morphisms of $\mathcal C$ such that $f$ is a retract of $g$ and $g$ is a weak equivalence, cofibration, or fibration, then so is $f$.
> 3. (Lifting) Define a map to be a *trivial cofibration* if it is both a cofibration and a weak equivalence. Similarly, define a map to be a *trivial fibration* if it is both a fibration and a weak equivalence. Then trivial cofibrations have the left lifting property with respect to fibrations, and cofibrations have the right lifting property with respect to trivial fibrations.
> 4. (Factorization) For any morphism $f$, $\alpha(f)$ is a cofibration, $\beta(f)$ is a trivial fibration, $\gamma(f)$ is a trivial cofibration, and $\delta(f)$ is a fibration

I do not understand the definition $1.1.3.(3)$ in the snippet above:
Does it say that if $f$ has l.l.p. w.r.t. $p$ and $f$ is a trivial cofibration **then**
$p$ is a **fibration** **OR** that if $f$ is a trivial cofibration and $p$ is a **fibration**
**then** $f$ has l.l.p. w.r.t. $p$ ?

Comment: I doubt I could answer this question, but I think people who can would find it helpful if you would say what book this comes from.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle. For commutative diagramms, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/how-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram).

Answer (score 2):

It says: Let $f:X'\rightarrow X'$ be a map and $C$ a class of maps suppose that for every element $Y\rightarrow Y'$, of $C$ if there exists a commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>>> Y\\
@V{f}VV @VV{c}V \\
X' @>>> Y'
\end{CD}$$

then there exists a map $X'\rightarrow Y$ which make the triangles commute. Then we say that $f$ has the letf lifting property in respect of the family $C$.

Now take $C$ be the class of cofibrations, we obtain that $f$ a trivial fibration.
If $C$ is the class of trivial cofibrations we obtain that $f$ is a fibration.

Comment: But the definition $1.1.3.3$ says: **if** $f$ is a trivial fibration and $c$ cofibration **then** $f$ has l.l.p. w.r.t. $c$. What you say is that if for all cofibrations $c$ has r.l.p. w.r.t. to $f$ **then** $f$ is a trivial fibration.